# Will Microsoft System Restore affect my Ubuntu OS?

Tags: windows, partitioning, microsoft

I have Ubuntu 16.04  and Windows 10 (Dual boot UEFI). If i use windows system restore to a restore point  BEFORE installing Ubuntu, will it affect my ubuntu partitions?
I only have one HDD C: with 6 partition including ubuntu swap and ext4 and the others are windows health, recovery etc.
I want to know if windows restore system will affect Ubuntu partitions or affect Ubuntu in any way.
thank you

Comment: It's a good question.  I wish I had a single drive system setup to test it with, but according to the recovery options https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options they are saying that "Restoring won’t affect your personal files, but it will remove apps, drivers, and updates installed after the restore point was made."  So my guess would be that it will not affect it.  But I am not 100% certain.