# System Restore in Windows will affect other partition?

Tags: windows, system

I have to partitions on a laptop. one for windows and the other for Ubuntu. does System restore to the previous point in windows will affect ubuntu partition??

I just wanted windows to be reset to the particular date

Comment: Why ask us that and not a windows user?

Comment: @Rinzwind I answered this question because it is a new question and the asker will read it, but there is  another older duplicate question that has no answers: [Will Microsoft System Restore affect my Ubuntu OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005991/will-microsoft-system-restore-affect-my-ubuntu-os?). If this question is closed I'll answer the other one. If this question has an upvoted answer I'll CV the other question as a duplicate of this one. If *both* questions are closed as off topic I will ignore both of them.

Answer (score 0):

From the official Microsoft [Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options) webpage:

> **Restore from a system restore point**
>
> This option takes your PC back to an earlier point in time, called a system restore point. Restore points are generated when you install a new app, driver, or Windows update, and when you create a restore point manually. Restoring won’t affect your personal files, but it will remove apps, drivers, and updates installed after the restore point was made.

Removing updates may include removing updates to the Windows bootloader which in turn can cause Ubuntu's grub bootloader to stop working. If this happens grub can be repaired by following the instructions in [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

If you restore back to a system restore point before a major update such as Windows 10 Anniversary Update and the more recent Windows 10 Creators Update, then Windows may try to reinstall the removed major update which can wipe out Linux partitions on MBR disks and also cause Ubuntu's grub bootloader to stop working.